# How to start developing for Amazon Fire TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I was requested to develop an Amazon Fire TV app, but I find difficult to understand the steps required to get on track.

As specified by the Amazon [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/setting-up-your-development-environment), the previously available Fire TV SDK add-on is now deprecated, and they suggest to just use the Android v17 Leanback Library.

To date, I do not have (yet) a Fire TV, and the official documentation is very poor and rather confused; I'm not able – then – to understand whether "pure" Android TV apps are fully compatible with Fire OS 5, so that developing for the Fire TV is actually the same as developing for a generic Amazon TV (from the SDK, to the virtual testing process).
In the case it isn't, what are the different steps I have to take into account?

Answer (score 5):

You should start with using `Android v17 Leanback Library`. There is a [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) available from Google that uses leanback library. Few things you might need to check for `firetv` like [speech recognition](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-sdk-frequently-asked-questions) (`SearchFragment` in the leanback library) is currently unsupported

> Fire OS 5 includes both support for Android TV functionality and the
>   leanback support library. Speech recognition (SearchFragment in the
>   leanback library) is currently unsupported.

and [global search](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/design-and-user-experience-guidelines) which is not customizable for individual apps for `firetv`

> Global search is provided system-wide and is not customizable for
>   individual apps. Developers may implement their own in-app search, but
>   it is not included in the global search function.

Also try to follow [pre-submission assessment guidelines](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/pre-submission-assessment-guide) and [developer FAQs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-sdk-frequently-asked-questions) when developing for a `firetv`.